# How to make many ajax requests for blobs to google app engine

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, jquery

I'd like to make many request to google app engine for blobs. This basic for loop method creates the right number of elements but they all point to the blob that was requested last.

```
for (key=0; key < keyList.length; key++){
    var keyUrl = '/serve_blob/audio/'+keyList[key];
    $.ajax({ url : keyUrl, type : 'GET', dataType : 'text',
        success : function(data, xhr, status) {
            renderTemp("#audioTable", "audioTemplate", {'audioSrc':keyUrl});
        }
    });
}
```

I can get a second request to work properly by calling it from the ajax complete callback. Is there a better way to get this to work for many requests?

Comment: Please, provide more details. It's really hard to understand what is your problem, and provided code doesn't contain things your talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the nature of a closure. When the code in the closure (eg, the code in your success function) executes, the value of `keyUrl` is whatever it was set to last - the value is not captured at the time the closure was defined.

To avoid this, put the ajax call inside a separate function, with `keyUrl` as a parameter, and call it from inside your loop.

Comment: Ok, thats exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you iterating on "key"?   You're not using it...

```
var keyUrl = '/serve_blob/audio/'+keyList[key];
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That was just an issue with my example.